# Rascal: Convert define to camelcase

Tags: string, rascal

I want to convert c-style define names to camelcase.
Example: BLA_BLA -> blaBla

I created the following function:

```
private str camelCaseName(n) {
    rVal = n;   
    if (contains(rVal, "_")) { 
        rVal = toLowerCase(rVal);
        for (pos <- findAll(rVal, "_")) {
            up = toUpperCase(stringChar(charAt(rVal, pos + 1)));
            charList = chars(rVal);
            charList = delete(charList, pos + 1);
            charList = insertAt(charList, pos + 1, charAt(up, 0));
            rVal = stringChars(charList);
        }
//      rVal = replaceAll(rVal, "_", "");
    }
    return rVal;
}
```

This works well for changing the case. However if I uncomment the replaceAll then a call that uses the string reports "Expected str, but got tuple[value,value,value]".

I guess there is an easier way to get this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what goes wrong with the `replaceAll` function, but I'd try the static checker on this code and read its error message.

Another way of writing the function:

```
private str camelCaseName(str n) {
    words = split("_", toLowerCase(n));

    return "<words[0]><for (w <- words[1..]) {><capitalize(w)><}>";
}
```

- I added a type to the parameter `n`, that's obligatory.
- String templates are a nice way of printing out stuff in a string.
- The `split` function is handy; it splits a string into list elements.
- The `capitalize` function changes the first letter of a word to a capital

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Comment: cool. pls accept the answer?